# Python Multiprocessing with Function and for-loop

Tags: python, function, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I am new to the topic multiprocessing and I am not sure how to use it for my task.
I have created a function for forecasting future values and now want to use multiprocessing to be able to compute more forecasts at once.
The functions takes the variables "id" (unique value in the dataframe), and the specific "dataframe".The result of this function is a dataframe with the forecasted values in it.

```
def forecast("id", dataframe):
  ...
  ...
  return forecast_dataframe
```

My first approach was this:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing import Process
import time


if __name__ == '__main__':
    id_list = df.id.unique()[1:16]

    t = time.perf_counter()

    # Init multiprocessing.Pool()
    print("CPU COUNT:", mp.cpu_count())
    pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count()-4)
    results = [pool.apply_async(prophet.forecast("ID3", df), args=(idx, df)) for idx in id_list]
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    print('Extracted in', time.perf_counter() - t)

    for i in range(len(results)):
        fb_forecast_output = pd.concat([fb_forecast_output, results[i].get()], axis=0)

    fb_forecast_output.to_csv('./data/output/fb_forecast_output.csv', index=False)
```

Somehow this is only computing forecasts for one ID repeated.
How can I use multiprocessing in the right way with a function like "def forecast"?

Thanks!

Comment: multiprocessing doesn't share data - main process has to save DataFrame in file and processes will have to read it from file - it may be faster to DataFrame file directly in function.

Comment: why do you use `ID3` for all execution? I'm not sure but maybe you should rather use function's name without `()` - `[pool.apply_async(prophet.forecast, args=(idx, df))]`. At least normal multiprocessing (withou async) needs function's name

Comment: @furas I think that could be the error. Somehow didn't see it, thanks.